# Подключение файла в Python и работа с его функциями

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Решил сделать себе программку и делать так чтобы всё не в один скрипт, а создать несколько скриптов и с ними взаимодействовать.
Сделал `Python Package` и сразу в нем появился `__init.py__`
Моя директива выгладить примерно так

```
C:\Users\Name\Documents\Python\p1\programs\main\pr
C:\Users\Name\Documents\Python\p1\programs\main\pr\m.py
C:\Users\Name\Documents\Python\p1\programs\main\pr\g.py
C:\Users\Name\Documents\Python\p1\programs\main\pr\main.py
```

И теперь вопрос в том что в файлах `m.py` `g.py` содержатся сами функции, а в `main.py` уже всё это будет происходить
Вопрос. Как мне заставить чтобы в `main.py` работали эти функции? Ибо как не пытался. Не выходит

Делал так `from po import g`
Можете с этим помочь чтобы все что находится в файле `g` мог подключать и использовать в `main`

Comment: Если это пакет, то в main.py используйте относительный импорт как `from .g import function`

Comment: я не особо понял, где у вас `__init__.py`

Comment: В корне директории